# Android application icon doesn't show in ActionBar

Tags: android

I'm working through some Android tutorials at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html

My understanding is that by default, the app icon should show in the action bar, but I'm not seeing it. I'm seeing comments in other posts that this behavior changed in SDK 21, but when I created the app in Android Studio, I specified a minimum SDK of 19. Is that irrelevant for this behavior?

Comment: My app icons never show in the action bar

Comment: Yes, the minSdkVersion is irrelevant. If you're using the Material theme (on API 21+) or appcompat theme, you won't get an app icon in the toolbar by default.

Comment: Thanks - I think the appcompat theme is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your activity.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Make sure the activity is `extends ActionBarActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, edit file style.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="app_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionbarstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="actionbarstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
</style>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application
    ....
    android:theme="@style/app_theme">
```